# How to open Google play store on firefox mobile instead native app

Tags: php, android, firefox, android-intent

I have an issue with Firefox on android, I can't redirect users to play store.

On Chrome for android I have a link like this:
`intent://www.xxxxx.com/home#Intent;scheme=xxxx;package=xxxxx.android.app;end`

When the user has installed the native app, the app is launched.
If the user doesn't have the native app we redirect him to play store.

When the user is in firefox for android we can launch the app but we can't redirect to the play store.

Does someone have an idea about this issue?

I have fin this blog article:
https://paul.kinlan.me/deep-app-linking-on-android-and-chrome/

Maybe fore firefox mobile it doesn't work like chrome ?

Comment: Why do you want them to go to the website rather than the app?

Comment: Some users don't know the app, we need a possibility to push a download link through the play store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was caused by outdated management of our deeplinks.

For android it's important to use this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

For iOS:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Comment: Your Android link points to Apple docs as well, C&P error?